# SQL Server Spatial: Is variable of type geometry or geography?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geometry, geography

Is there a property or method that will tell me whether a SQL Server spatial object is of type geometry or geography?

Comment: Please check. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Aside: One way that doesn't work is `SQL_Variant_Property( Foo, 'BaseType' )` since a `sql_variant` can't contain a spatial datatype. It's a handy tool for most datatypes.

Comment: Thank you; it  is what I was looking for but, as you say, it does not work for spatial data types.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a property or method that will tell me whether a SQL Server spatial object is of type geometry or geography?

geometry and geography are simply different types.  So your question is equivalent to asking how to tell the difference between a date and a varchar.

The type will be specified in the table definition, a local variable declaration, a parameter declaration, result set metadata, the `sys.columns` catalog view, etc.